# Add pvalue to subgroups with gtsummary

Tags: r, p-value, gtsummary

```
library(survival)
library(gtsummary)

tbl <-
  trial[c("age", "grade", "trt")] %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_p()
```

How do I add the pvalue to the different grades to see if there is a difference between drug A and drug B?

Comment: I wonder whether this is a well defined request on statistical grounds? Do we have sufficient reason to think that  the underlying model if such exists (which is not at all apparent from the results of `str(trial)`) has calculated parameters that would allow p-values to be calculated?